# Swift : Animate CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

In the code below I am trying to animate a `CALayer` from the left side of the screen to the right side of the screen as the user is holding down on the screen (longPressGestureRecognizer). When the user lifts their finger, the `CALayer` pauses.

```
var l = CALayer()
var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpView()
}

func setUpView(){
    l.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
    l.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")
}

func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    if(sender.state == .Began) { //User is holding down on screen
        print("Long Press Began")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.maxX * 2
        animation.duration = 30
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(l)
        l.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")
    }
    else { //User lifted Finger
        print("Long press ended")
        print("l width: \(l.bounds.size.width)")
        pauseLayer(l)
    }
}

func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    var pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

I have two issues:

1. When i print the width of the `CALayer` after the animation (when user lifts finger) its always 0. I animate the width, and its expanding, thus I do not know why it does not give me the new width of the `CALayer`.
2. After the user lifts their finger, and then holds down again, the `CALayer` disappears. I need it to remain on the screen, and create another `CALayer`, I do not delete it in any way, so i do not understand why it is as well disappearing. I checked the memory the object still exists.

**UPDATE to issue #2** : I believe to create another `CALayer` I can't just add the layer again. I must either create a copy or create a `UIView` that I can add the layer to. I still do not understand why it is disappearing though.

Comment: You should be setting the target bound to the layer before animating it.

Comment: Thank you for the response! What exactly do you mean? Could you answer the question?
Some were saying i should create a copy of the CALayer. @Shripada

Comment: I have tried to answer, check it out -@originalAlchemist

Comment: You're awesome!! Check out my comment! @Shripada

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you are trying to resize the layer when user is holding down. Here is a function that can be used to resize a given layer:

If you want origin to be pegged to the left, you will need to set the anchor of the layer first:

```
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1);

func resizeLayer(layer:CALayer, newSize: CGSize) {

    let oldBounds = layer.bounds;
    var newBounds = oldBounds;
    newBounds.size = size;


    //Ensure at the end of animation, you have proper bounds
    layer.bounds = newBounds

    let boundsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    positionAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: oldBounds)
    positionAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: newBounds)
    positionAnimation.duration = 30
}
```

In your case, I am not sure where you are resuming the paused layer though. Also observe every time user taps, a new animation gets added in your handleLongPress method! and this will have unwanted effect. Ideally you need to initiate animation only for the first time, and later, just resume the paused animation you started earlier.

```
//Flag that holds if the animation already started..
var animationStarted = false

func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

  //User is holding down on screen
  if(sender.state == .Began){

    if(animationStarted == false){
      let targetBounds =  CalculateTargetBounds() //Implement this to your need
      resizeLayer(layer, targetBounds)
      animationStarted = true
    }else {
      resumeLayer(layer)
    }
  }else {
    pauseLayer(layer)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! The only thing is I want to create a new layer each time the user holds down. The next layer's origin will be from where the last layer left off, it will look like one continuous bar, but its really multiple placed next to each other. The reason i do this is because i then store them into an array, and can delete them when needed. I need to track every hold down and how long the bar gets, then delete it if needed(don't worry about deleting though).Please Help!!

Comment: You sure this code is right?  You defined a function `resizeLayer` that takes a parameter `newSize` yet you're not using it inside.  Instead you're referencing `size` which I'm not sure where that's coming from. If it's because you're inside a subclass of UIView, then even so, `oldBounds` and `newBounds` will always be equal since you're setting the new from the old, then setting the new size from the current (i.e. old.) ...or am I missing something?